# python function in php

Tags: php, python, hash, byte

i want this function from python in php. Id is an long.

```
def encrypted_id(id):
byte1 = bytearray('3go8&$8*3*3h0k(2)2', 'utf-8')
byte2 = bytearray(id, 'utf-8')
byte1_len = len(byte1)
for i in range(len(byte2)):
    byte2[i] = byte2[i] ^ byte1[i % byte1_len]
result = md5(byte2).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
result = result.replace('/', '_')
result = result.replace('+', '-')
return result
```

what i have:

```
public function encrypted_id($dfsid) {
    $chars=(string)$dfsid;
    $key ='3go8&$8*3*3h0k(2)2';
    $byte1_len=count($key);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($chars); $i++){
       //print_r(unpack("H*",$chars[$i])^unpack("H*",$key[$i % byte1_len]));
    }      
}
```

Many thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption. And MD5 is not a safe hashing algorithm.

Comment: how can do this in php:
 byte2[i] = byte2[i] ^ byte1[i % byte1_len] and this  md5(byte2).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]

Comment: @RobFoley you are right but base64 is encyption

Comment: Base64 is absolutely not encryption. It is encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may help you.

```php
function encrypted_id($dfsid) {
    $key ='3go8&$8*3*3h0k(2)2';
    $key_len = strlen($key);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($dfsid); $i++){
        $dfsid[$i] = $dfsid[$i] ^ $key[$i % $key_len];
    }
    $raw_code = base64_encode(md5($dfsid, true));
    $code = str_replace(array('/', '+'), array('_', '-'), $raw_code);
    return $code;
}
$id = 3335918278827174;
echo encrypted_id(number_format($id, 0, '', ''));
```